# In MATLAB, given some decimal numbers, any efficient way to find minimum length of mantissa and exponent for custom floating-point binary?

Tags: matlab, floating-point

If I want to represent some decimal numbers by using custom floating-point binary, how to efficiently find the minimum length of mantissa and exponent that will maintain precision needed to distinguish these numbers?

For example: Given three decimal numbers 1.2020, 1.2019 and 2.1010. What is the minimum length of mantissa and exponent in custom FP binary that will provide enough precision and range to let them remain distinguishable?

Comment: If you have the decimal number, you already have the mantissa and the exponent. So, what's the question? Please be more specific

Comment: Give an example of your input, output, and how you calculate in mind.

Comment: Are you really asking for a floating point and not for fixed point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: if you want to represent numbers with `p` decimal digits of precision recoverably in binary floating-point, you'll need to use at least `ceil(1 + p log2(10))` bits of precision in your binary format.  For the example you give, with 5-digit decimal numbers, you'll need at least 18 bits of binary precision. In particular, IEEE 754 single precision is good enough for that particular example.

Longer answer: Let's forget about exponent restrictions for the moment; that's not the interesting part.  Fix a precision `p > 0` for the decimal floating-point type and a precision `q > 0` for the the binary floating-point type.

Let `D` be the set of all positive real numbers that are expressible in `p` significant decimal digits or fewer; that is, `D` contains all numbers of the form `n × 10^e` for integers `n` and `e` with `0 < n <= 10^p` (and `e` unrestricted).  Similarly, let `B` be the set of all positive real numbers exactly representable in binary in precision `q`, so `B` is the set of all numbers of the form `m × 2^f` for integers `m` and `f` with `0 < m <= 2^q`.

The rounding-to-nearest operation gives us a well-defined function `round` from `D` to `B`.  (For definiteness, let's follow the usual floating-point conventions and say that halfway cases are rounded to even.)  We're interested in knowing when this function is injective: that is, when distinct entries of `D` remain distinct after rounding to our binary format.

The following is a special case of a general result about floating-point base conversions:

> A necessary and sufficient condition for the `round` function from `D` to `B` to be injective is that
>
> `10^p < 2^(q-1)`
>
> Moreover, when this condition is satisfied the round-to-nearest operation from `B` to `D` gives an inverse to `round`.

See for example the ["Handbook of Floating-Point Arithmetic"](http://www.springer.com/birkhauser/mathematics/book/978-0-8176-4704-9) by Muller et. al., Theorem 1 of section 2.7 for a general statement of the theorem and a reference to a proof.

Taking logs to base `2`, rearranging, and noting that we can never have actual equality between `10^p` and `2^(q-1)`, the above condition can be rewritten as

> q >= ceil(1 + p log2(10))

So if you're dealing with decimal values with at most 5 significant digits, the minimum binary precision you can get away with is 18 bits.

Similarly, this tells us that IEEE 754 single precision (`q = 24`) is good for representing decimal values with at most 6 significant digits (because `10^6 < 2^23` but `10^7 > 2^23`), while double precision (`q = 53`) can handle up to 15 decimal digits faithfully.  IEEE 754 quadruple precision (`q = 113`) gets us 33 decimal digits.

Interestingly, the above statement has nothing in particular to do with the bases `10` and `2`; essentially the same statement works for an arbitrary pair of bases, provided only that the two bases are not both powers of a common base (for example, converting from base 8 to base 16, or from base 27 to base 9).  Reversing the bases `2` and `10`, the above gives us the well-known result that `17` significant decimal digits are enough to represent a 53-bit IEEE 754 binary floating-point number faithfully.

Figuring out the necessary exponent range is much more straightforward: if you can describe the max and min possible absolute values of your input, you can easily find suitable corresponding binary minimum and maximum exponent.  Just one thing to be careful of: if you're using an IEEE 754-style binary format with gradual underflow, you'll want to make sure to steer clear of the subnormal range.

Comment: Thanks Mark, for a decimal number say 1.1212, it has 5 significant digits so I can find proper precision based on your answer. However what about 0.0002? It has only one significant digit but it seems I still need 18bits precision in floating-point binary. So how should I determine decimal digits p? In addition, for decimal group say 1000.1, 1.001, 1.001, should I determine precision based on the max number of decimal digits (5 in this case) and then determine exponent to have a bound > 1000.1?

Comment: You want to look at the set of numbers you need to represent as a whole:  so yes, determine the precision based on the maximum number of significant digits (and exponents as you describe).

Answer (score 1):

'Enough' precision is dependent on your requirement. Single precision floating point number use 23 bits for precision and double floating point precision uses 52 bits for precision.

Since floating point number are internally represented by fractions of `1/2^n` some numbers can be represented exactly (for instance 0.5). For more information see the following articles:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_precision_floating-point_format

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_precision_floating-point_format